# Trouble in Inject Service in Other Service Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have got trouble when inject service in another Service.
I got a ContactService to get data from the server with the handleError method.
I got an AlertService to throw error from handleError Method.
I have already declared both contactService and AlertService in my Core Module.
But when I called alertService.submitNewMessage it shown that this.alertService is undefined.
Please help

```
@Injectable()
export class AlertService {
  private $currentMessages: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');
  public currentMessages: Observable<string> = this.$currentMessages.asObservable();
  constructor() { }

  submitNewMessage(msg: string): void {
    this.$currentMessages.next(msg);
  }

}
```

And Contact Service

```
@Injectable()    
export class ContactService {


      private contactsUrl = 'http://localhost/customers';
      constructor(
                  private http: Http,
                  private router: Router,
                  private alertService: AlertService
                  ) { }

      getContactsFromService(): Observable<SubmitCustomerHttp[]>  {
        return this.http.get(this.contactsUrl)
                        .map(this.extractData)
                        .catch(this.handleError);
      }

      private extractData(res: Response) {
        return HttpHelper.extractData(res);
      }

      handleError(error: Response | any) {
        let errMsg: string;
        console.log('Receive error: ', error);
        if (error instanceof Response) {
          const body = error.json() || '';
          const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
          errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
          if (error.status === 500 || 400 || 404) {
            window.alert(errMsg);
            this.alertService.submitNewMessage(errMsg);
            return errMsg;
          }
        } else {
          errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
          console.log('Error Message: ', errMsg);
          return null;
        }
      }
    }
```

My Core Module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule

  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    AlertService,
    ContactService,

  ]
})


export class CoreModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: CoreModule,
      providers: [
        AlertService,
        ContactService,

      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: where is the code for alertService.submitNewMessage?

Comment: @Sajeetharan sorry, my mistake, I will fix it

Comment: you contactservice is not decorated with @Injectable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I suspect is related to

```
return this.http.get(this.contactsUrl)
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError);
```

This registers the class methods as callbacks, which is incorrect because `this` will not bind correctly.

You can fix this by wrapping these in arrow-functions, so that `this` will still refer to the service and not to the callback function when the code inside is reached:

```
return this.http.get(data => this.contactsUrl(data))
                .map(data => this.extractData(data))
                .catch(data => this.handleError(data));
```

Comment: I have changed like your comment but still that message: eError: Cannot read property 'submitNewMessage' of undefined

Comment: Hey, guy. Thanks for your help. After rebuild several times, 'this' context has been fixed